# To do to have something done ... what is the difference?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, comparative-constructions

> A seven year-old Indian girl has complained to the police ***to*** ***have her
>   father arrested*** after he failed to build a toilet in their home as
>   promised.

Source: https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2018/12/12/seven-year-old-indian-girl-tries-have-father-arrested-fails

Why the writer used ***to have her father arrested*** not simply ***to arrest her father***?

My guess is that form indicates surprising .. when we should rather use that form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We use have + object + -ed form when we talk about someone doing
>   something for us which we ask or instruct them to do. It emphasises
>   the process/action rather than who performs it:
>
> We’re having the house painted next week. (We are not going to paint
>   the house ourselves. Someone else will paint it. The emphasis is on
>   the fact that the house is being painted rather than who is doing it.)

Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/passive/have-something-done

***to have her father arrested*** type of sentences are called [Causatives](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/causatives-have-get.html) meaning ***to get her father arrested*** (by that seven year-old Indian girl), whereas ***to arrest her father*** is a simple sentence which does not fit in this scenario unless **A seven year-old Indian girl** had authority to do so (ie to arrest someone).

Comment: See also: [OED *have* (v.) sense 28a](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/84705#eid1807595) (paywall); [Wiktionary *have*, v. sense 11](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have#Verb)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question lies with the verb **complain**.

When you think that **to arrest her father** is a valid complement, you're treating **complain** as if it were the same as **ask** or **want** :

> She asked the police to arrest her father.
>
> She wanted the police to arrest her father.

But **complain** is not quite like those verbs.  We complain **to** someone:

a) **about** something

b) **that** something is such and such ...

c) IN ORDER TO do something on our own behalf

d) IN ORDER TO have them do something on our behalf

It is the sense of "in order to" which makes **complain** different from **ask** and **want**.

This doesn't make sense:

> She complained to the police in order to arrest her father.

because she wanted *them* to do something:

> She complained to the police in order to have them arrest her father.

or

> She complained to the police in order to have her father (be) arrested (by them).